# Html Select Option

Tags: jquery, html, spring-mvc

I have a list box with options the itemValue is a String and the order in which it is being displayed is inaccurate.

I used on the $(document).ready(function(){$("#item").val(1) and set the index position of the item to the first in the list. By default it is set to an option in the list based on alphabetical order, this is not what i want.

Using JQuery to set the initial value index i want works, however when i post the page if there are any errors on the page when the page is returned the value of the item in the list goes back to value i set in the document.ready () function. How can i over come this.

**Code**;

**jquery**

```
$(document).ready(function(){

        $("#skinColorId").val(1);
});
```

**html:**

Data is coming from the Database

```
<li>
<form:label for="skinColorId" path="skinColorId">Select Skin Color</form:label>     
<form:select path="skinColorId" id="skinColorId" title="Select Skin Color">
<form:options items = "${skinColor.skinColorList}" itemValue="colorCode" itemLabel="colorDesc"/>
</form:select>          
<form:errors path="skinColorId" class="errors"/><label class="colorPreviewer" id="skinColorPreviewer">color previewer</label>
</li>
```

**Sample of Data:**

colorId|colorDesc|colorCode
155||Select Color||#FFFFFF
156||Aqua||#00FFFF
157||Aquamarine||#7FFFD4
158||Azure||#F0FFFF
159||Beige||#F5F5DC
160||Bisque||#FFE4C4
161||Black||#000000
162||BlanchedAlmond||#FFEBCD

Comment: can you provide your code so it will be easy to help you..

Comment: Please show us some markup and code so that we can help you. Perhaps set up a fiddle.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try setting the default value by using "selected".

For eg:

```
<option value="value" selected="selected">choose one</option>
```

And after posting... check for the response from the server.

```
if (response.success) {
  //clear the items value by using ( $('#item').html('');})
else{
  //if response if failed... or some error occured
  //then have the same value for your option tag
}
```

You really don't need to check for $(document).ready neither to set the value in jquery...

Try it... Hope it works :)...